# Bus Error on Mongodb MongoClient.connect() for Raspberry Pi ARM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, arm, raspberry-pi

I have tried executing this node script on an x64 computer, and it appears to work fine.

However, the same script reports a bus error when run on the Raspberry Pi. It gives a [6047.715610] Unhandled Fault: alignment exception error, with the error reported on the next line, as a Bus error.  It appears that the error stems from MongoClient.connect().

The script utilizes MongoClient and GridStore from the mongodb module. In addition, I have attempted a re-installation from this repository (which appears to do a `gyp-rebuild`), and it fails.

Is there any compilation option that should be set?

Comment: Where does your mongodb come from? A Linux distribution? Which one?
Does your mongodb work in any other scenarios?
Debian does not build mongodb for anything other than its i386/amd64 ports, since at least historically it was not written portably (heavy use of pointer casting ignoring alignment requirements).

Comment: Thanks!  I managed to fix it by changing a compilation flag.  Was told that ARM devices are more picky about memory.  See below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the error by pulling the repo from github, editing `bson.h`, and doing a `node-gyp rebuild` on it.

Apparently, the error is caused by a compilation option which is not supported by ARM devices.
 Just in case anyone is interested:

1. Git clone repository here: `https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native`
2. Open `./node-mongodb-native/node_modules/bson/ext/bson.h`
3. Change `#define USE_MISALIGNED_MEMORY_ACCESS` from `1` to `0`
4. do a `node-gyp rebuild` to recompile the library.

This worked for me.